# Hiking trip distribution

Tags: combinatorics, information-theory

I have a real life problem. My friends and I are going on a hiking trip and there's a bunch of items (mostly food) that we want to distribute among us so everyone carries approximately equal weight. Assume I have a list of $n$ items each of weight $w_i$, $i = 1,\dots , n$. How can I find the best distribution among $N$ people? That means everyone carries approximately $w=\sum_{i=1}^n w_i / N$.

I tried to use the theory of information entropy but I wasn't able to figure it out. Also, I'm not quite sure about tagging this - please correct if it's wrong. I will be glad for any kind of advice.

Comment: Have you heard about the [partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem)?